# Move MultiBit from Mac to Windows

Tags: wallet, client, multibit, mac, windows

I'm an IT consultant in Australia and I'm pretty green when it comes to BitCoin and wallets and the like.

I've been contacted by a client with a MacBook Pro that cannot be repaired and he is looking to switch to a Windows laptop.
He says he has a MultiBit wallet on the Mac which contains all his 'Private Keys'... What I would like to know is if all of this data can be transferred onto a Windows environment with minimal fuss...  Can this be done?

He also says he has a "bridge" into his "trezor" that he needs as well.  Being an older client, he might not be pronouncing things right or his understanding might not help him convey exactly what he means.  But I'm assuming the "bridge" is some sort of VPN or browser add-in that creates a link between the "trezor" service he's using.
If I cannot boot the Mac, how would I determine where and what data this is and how to transfer it across to Windows as well?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I would like to know is if all of this data can be transferred onto a Windows environment with minimal fuss.

Yep. Find [the data directory](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35938/where-does-multibit-keep-its-data-directory) on the Mac. Copy out multibit.wallet. Install MultiBit on Windows. Find [the data directory](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35938/where-does-multibit-keep-its-data-directory) on the Windows computer. Copy it there.

> He also says he has a "bridge" into his "trezor" that he needs as well.

He's probably talking about the Trezor plugin. [This page](http://doc.satoshilabs.com/trezor-user/settingup.html) explains how to set that up in the first paragraph.