# Where does MultiBit keep its data directory?

Tags: multibit

Where does MultiBit keep its data directory? What is the wallet inside called?

Comment: For technical information about MultiBit Classic you should refer to its help: https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_contents.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Windows

Type `%APPDATA%\MultiBit` into the address bar of File Explorer.

If that doesn't work, try

- Windows XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\<your name>\Application Data\Bitcoin`
- Windows Vista and later: `C:\Users\<your name>\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin`

#### Mac

1. Open Finder, then open the Go menu.
2. Click "Go to Folder..."
3. Type `~/Library/Application Support/MultiBit`

#### Linux

Open your home directory. Look for the MultiBit folder.

#### Wallet name

The wallet is always called `multibit.wallet`. It's the equivalent of `wallet.dat` in Bitcoin-Qt.