# How do I see what version of bitcoin core my wallet uses

Tags: client, multibit, bitcoin-core-development

I use the multibit wallet which I understand doesn't download the whole bitcoin core i.e. the entire block chain, but it must use the bitcoin core protocol right? So how do I see which version of the protocol my wallet is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Multibit data directory](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35938/where-does-multibit-keep-its-data-directory), there is a file called `log/multibit.log`. When you connect to a peer, it will write something like this to the log:

```
20:01:26.124 [bitcoinj user thread] DEBUG o.m.c.b.BitcoinPeerEventListener - Connected to peer:
client version: 70002
local services: 1
time:           1424228484
my addr:        [xx.xx.xx.xx]:51127
their addr:     [xx.xx.xx.xx]:8333
sub version:    /Satoshi:0.10.0/
best height:    343977
delay tx relay: true
```

The 'sub version' field contains the version in a human readable format. The 'client version' field contains a machine-readable protocol version.

Comment: Perfect thanks Nick! I appreciate the link to finding the Multibit data directory as well.  So bounus question, I see my wallet last used Satoshi:0.9.2.1, but I see it skips around, what determines which version it uses?

Comment: @JonathanChadFaling It connects to nodes owned by other people, so it's whatever they decide to run.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Looking at https://blockchain.info/connected-nodes, lots of nodes have same 'client version' but vastly differently 'sub versions'.

Comment: @Jus12 It's because the protocol version and the client version are different.

Answer (score 0):

On Bitcoin Core go to Windows > Console (CTRL+T).
Then, type:

```
getwalletinfo
```

Should show you a json with the wallet version.
Not sure if multibit software has that option thought.

Answer (score -2):

You can find this out on the command line with:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getinfo
```

This will give you an output like this:

```
{   
    "version" : 90400,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.62950000,
    "blocks" : 323377,
    "timeoffset" : -5,
    "connections" : 9,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 1.00000000,
    "testnet" : true,
    "keypoololdest" : 1412131069,
    "keypoolsize" : 101,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00001000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

Version is the actual bitcoin core version and probably what you're looking for.

Comment: This appears to get the version of a local bitcoind instance. I don't think that's what the asker is asking about.

Comment: Gah, you're right